# How to Increase/Change font size from using combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, font-size

I have a gridview with five columns. from the second gridview cells I have a column called font size which I have used combo-box and give static numbers like (2.4.6.8.10).

The purpose of font size is, when you select any number from the combo box, it must change the font size text for that row.

I have created a combo-box and a label which I will select the font size and the label will change the text size according to the selected size. I am falling to apply this to the datagridview where it will change the whole cells for that row

code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblchangesize.Font = new Font(lblchangesize.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem), lblchangesize.Font.Style);
}
```

I tried to apply this to the gridview but it is not working

```
   Dictionary<int, Font> rowFont = new Dictionary<int, Font>();

    public void selectedRowsFont(Font F)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in Gridview_Output.SelectedRows)
        {
            rowFont[row.Index] = F;
        }
    }
    private void Gridview_Output_CellFormatting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        Font F = null;
        if (!rowFont.TryGetValue(e.RowIndex, out F))
            F = Gridview_Output.Font;

        e.CellStyle.Font = F;
    }
```

Comment: I want to apply this to my datagridview, when you change font size it must change the whole row. the code above was my example when working with the label.

Comment: and what kind of problems do you have with the DataGridView? what have you tried?

Comment: see my updated code which i was trying. i just don't have an idea on this

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event. Then set the font `e.CellStyle.Font = ...`

You will need to maintain a Font lookup based on row index, and use `e.RowIndex` as the key.

Edit:

```
// member variable:
Dictionary<int,Font> rowFont = new Dictionary<int,Font>();

public void SetSelectedRowsFont(Font f) {
   // foreach selected row,
   // rowFont[row.Index] = f;
}

// ... in cell formatting:
Font f = null;
if (!rowFont.TryGetValue(e.RowIndex, out f))
    f = this.Font;
e.CellStyle.Font = f;
```

Comment: @prosts You are setting `lblchangesize.Font`. Instead it should be `e.CellStyle.Font`.

Comment: i have followed your instructions and now i have a problem with Convert.ToInt32(FontOut.SelectedItem) which says it doesn't contain the defination. i have changed the code as you can see my updated code.. Please help me!

Comment: @prosts See edit. You will need to cache the Fonts if they can be different for each row.

Comment: @ Loathing check my updated code, it seems like we moving to the right direction now. it gaves this error ; //Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to 'System.Drawing.Font

Comment: Hi Loathing,Are you there?

Comment: can anyone please help me do this?

Comment: Change `this.Font` to `Gridview_Output.Font`.

Comment: Set a break point in `CellFormatting` and confirm your font dictionary contains values.